# Variable price field for donation

Tags: commerce

Is it possible to create a variable price field where the user may enter any donation amount they like.

Comment: you can try https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_donate/releases/8.x-1.x-dev

Comment: I installed this module and was able to see the form as a block.  I couldn't figure out how to use it in an order item type field.  The module is still in alpha and has limits for its configuration.

I would like to find a way to use an order item type field to accept a variable price input which the buyer can enter.

Comment: http://github.com/bojanz/donation_example might help